# When I reload my react application the changes in state gets reloaded however I have used hooks to manage the localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have used useEffect() here but when I am checking the localstorage the length shown is zero however I have used the react hooks correctly. I have made a separate file in my todolist app to manage the localstorage whose code is mentioned above.

```
const getLocalStorage = () => {
  let todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
  if (todos) {
    return (list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")))
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};

export const TodoWrapperLocalStorage = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getLocalStorage());
  useEffect(() => {
    if (todos.length > 0 && todos != null) {
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
    }
  }, [todos]);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem statement here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution you looking for, in your `useEffect`, you're checking if `todos.length > 0 && todos != null`
before saving to local storage. The problem here is that
`localStorage.setItem` is synchronous, and it doesn't return any errors if it
fails. So, it might be a better practice to directly stringify and save the
todos without the if condition like this:

```
export const TodoWrapperLocalStorage = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getLocalStorage());

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);

}
```